# mongoose auto create subdocument in ref field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, ecmascript-6

considering this schema:

file1:

```
const dishSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
}
class Dish extends Model {}


dishSchema.loadClass(Dish);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Dish', dishSchema);
```

file2:

```
Const offerSchema = new Schema({
    dish: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dish'
    }
class Offer extends Model {}


offerSchema.loadClass(Offer);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Offer', offerSchema);
```

right now I need to create a dish, and then create an offer with the id of the dish: `Dish.create({name: "foo}).then(dish => Offer.create({dish: dish.id}))`

does anyone know any package or option to automate this pattern?
so the final proccess will be something like this: `Offer.create({dish: {name: "foo"}})`

using dish as embeded document is not possible as I use it any many other schemas

Thanks

Comment: I guess this is possible with pre-save hook. I wouldn't suggest to introduce such magic because it will just make things more complicated. Considering that you've already got existing dish, you won't be able to do `Offer.create({dish: dish.id})` in this case. Possibly custom method like `createWithDish` would be a better idea.

Comment: Thanks, I limited to client side requirements, so i have to implement this behaviour, i tried the pre save hook but its seems to do nothing (you can take a look here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2228), anyway, this hook accept both methods (id and object for create), so if I'll manage to make it work it will be the perfect solution for me